# W3.CSS Center Pagination items for overflow

Tags: html, css, pagination, centering

I am using W3.CSS to make a simple pagination for my website, as seen below...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="w3-center footer w3-light-grey">
  <ul class="w3-pagination w3-border w3-round">
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">&laquo;</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">4</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">5</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">6</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">7</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">8</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">9</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">10</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">11</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">12</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">13</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">14</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">15</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">16</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">17</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">18</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">19</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">20</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="w3-hover-blue" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tutorial">&raquo;</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, there are alot of items in it, and it looks ugly on mobile devices as it fills up lots of lines, with left alignment...

[image]

What I want to be able to do, is center the elements in the middle, so it looks a little bit better than what it does now. I tried `text-align:center` on the `ul` but it didn't work. How can I center it?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7bypz02b/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use text-align center in ul, and display:inline-block for li:

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    height:20px;
    text-align:center;}

li {
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    margin-right:10px;}
```

My example here: https://jsfiddle.net/mickey_dt/whh0fdu6/

Comment: That works on desktop, but not on mobile http://upgradeck.businesscatalyst.com/tutorials/basic/html/index.html

Comment: I tested with F12 tool on Edge + Firefox and it worked. Are you sure of setting inline-block for li? http://imgur.com/I6faP7a, http://imgur.com/nrY4ZNH

Comment: Yes that works now. I was selecting the classes wrong.